# Dealing with long drawing operations

Tags: android, graphics, drawing, xamarin.android

I have a drawing operation that is sometimes going to be slow.  There is no getting around that.  The problem I am seeing is that sometimes, text that is supposed to be drawn near the end of the operation does not appear.  It seems to be pretty random -- from essentially the same drawing operation, sometimes the text will show up, and sometimes it won't, or only a very small portion of the characters will show up.  Is there any way to prevent that behavior?

If it matters, this is under Xamarin.

EDIT: here are some of my drawing callbacks.  What you would see typically is 100 or so calls to DrawLine, then a few DrawText calls, followed by maybe 1000 line segments via MoveTo/LineTo with the occasional DrawPath mixed in, and finally a smaller number of calls to DrawText type stuff.  The problem occurs in the text from the final DrawText calls.  Part of the issue is that the callbacks themselves ultimately come from a mathematical function whose evaluation time is unpredictable, as the function itself is entered by the user.  However, right now, the problem is happening even with simple functions.

Also possibly relevant -- the function itself comes from ANTLR.  When I substitute in a static function, (bypassing ANTLR), the problem does not occur.

```
public override void DrawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
  Paint p = new Paint();
  p.Color = _color;
  p.StrokeWidth = this.StrokeWidth;
  _canvas.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, p);
}

public override void MoveTo(float x, float y) {
  this._path.MoveTo(x, y);
}

public override void LineTo(float x, float y) {
  this._path.LineTo(x, y);
}

public override void DrawPath() {
  if (!this._path.IsEmpty) {
    using (Paint paint = new Paint()) {
      float strokeWidth = this.StrokeWidth;
      paint.StrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
      paint.Color = _color;
      paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
      this._canvas.DrawPath(this._path, paint);
      this._path = new Android.Graphics.Path(); //we drew what we wanted, now we need to create a new path in which to draw more stuff
    }
  }
}

private void DrawSingleLineText(AttributedString attributedString, float x, float y) {
  using (Paint p = new Paint()) {
    p.SetARGB(attributedString.Color.A, attributedString.Color.R, attributedString.Color.G, attributedString.Color.B);
    p.TextSize = attributedString.Font.PointSize;
    _canvas.DrawText(attributedString.Text, x, y, p);
  }
}
```

Comment: We need to see some code, it would determine how you are handling the processes.

Comment: What portion?  As though it is going offscreen at the bottom?

Comment: No, as in there is a bit of grayness in the correct location, but nothing recognizable as text.